# Limit the lifetime of a batch job

Tags: spring, batch-processing, spring-batch

Is there a way to limit the lifetime of a running spring-batch job to e.g. 23 hours?

We start a batch job daily by a cron job and he job takes about 9 hours. It happened under some circumstances that the DB connection was so slow that the job took over 60 hours to complete. The problem is that the next job instance gets started by the cronjob the next day - and then anotherone the day after - and anotherone...

If this job is not finished within e.g. 23 hours, I want to terminate it and return an error. Is there a way to do that out-of-the-box with spring-batch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a [StepListener](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/core/StepListener.html) you can stop a job by calling `StepExecution#setTerminateOnly`.

```
stepBuilderFactory
...
.writer(writer)
.listener(timeoutListener)
...
.build()
```

And the TimeoutListener could look like this

```
@Component
public class TimeoutListener implements StepListener {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    @BeforeStep
    public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

    @BeforeRead
    public void beforeRead() {
        if (jobShouldStop()) {
            stepExecution.setTerminateOnly();
        }
    }

    private boolean jobShouldStop() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This will gracefully stop the job, without forcefully terminate any running steps.

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch specifically avoids the issue of job orchestration which this falls into.  That being said, you could add a listener to your job that checks for other instances running and calls stop on them before beginning that one.  Not knowing what each job does, I'm not sure how effective that would be, but it should be a start.

Answer (score 1):

If you write your own job class to launch the process you can make your class implement StatefulJob interface, which prevents concurrent launches of the same job. Apart from that you can write your own monitoring and stop the job programatically after some period, but it will require some custom coding, I dont know if there is anything build-in for such use case.